# Get value of next element in array of arrays

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array, foreach

I have an array containing an array key of a date, with the value being another array.

```
Array ( [2017-01-01] => Array ( [available] => 1 ) [2017-01-02] => Array ( [available] => ) [2017-01-03] => Array ( [available] => 1 ) )
```

I'm trying to find a way of seeing if an unavailable day is the last or first of a given set of unavailable days. I'm using the following code, but getting an error of "Only variables can be passed by reference".

```
foreach ( $calendar as $date ) {
    if ( $date["available"] == 1 ) {
        if ( next( $date["available"] != 1 ) ) {
            echo $date . ' end';
        }
    }
}
```

I can see why this isn't working, but can't think of a way I can achieve what I want.

Comment: is it have the 0 index

Comment: I guess so, as it's the first. Unless I'm being thick, which is entirely possible.

Comment: Okay, so no, it doesn't have the 0 index. Will update the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you cannot use next on an value, next is used on array inner index.

```
<?php
$calendar = array ( '2017-01-01' => array ( 'available' => 1 ), '2017-01-02' => array ( 'available' => ''), '2017-01-03' => array ( 'available' => 1 ) );
while(current($calendar))
{
    if(current($calendar)['available'] == 1)
    {
        if(next($calendar)['available'] != 1)
            var_dump(current($calendar));
            echo 'end'."\n";
    }
    next($calendar);
}
```

Comment: Was starting to think I was going to need to use while rather than foreach, thanks very much.